# How do I save a trained model in PyTorch?

Tags: python, serialization, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

How do I save a trained model in PyTorch? I have read that:

1. [`torch.save()`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md#torchsavefilename-object--format-referenced)/[`torch.load()`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md#object-torchloadfilename--format-referenced) is for saving/loading a serializable object.
2. [`model.state_dict()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict)/[`model.load_state_dict()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) is for saving/loading model state.

Comment: I think it's because torch.save() save all the intermediate variables as well, like intermediate outputs for back propagation use. But you only need to save the model parameters, like weight/bias etc. Sometimes the former can be much larger than the latter.

Comment: I tested `torch.save(model, f)` and `torch.save(model.state_dict(), f)`. The saved files have the same size. Now I am confused. Also, I found using pickle to save model.state_dict() extremely slow. I think the best way is to use `torch.save(model.state_dict(), f)` since you handle the creation of the model, and torch handles the loading of the model weights, thus eliminating possible issues. Reference: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/saving-torch-models/838/4

Comment: Seems like PyTorch have addressed this a bit more explicitly in their [tutorials section](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)—there's lots of good info there that's not listed in the answers here, including saving more than one model at a time and warm starting models.

Comment: what is wrong with using `pickle`?

Comment: @CharlieParker torch.save is based on pickle. The following is from the tutorial linked above:

"[torch.save] will save the entire module using Python’s pickle module. The disadvantage of this approach is that the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used when the model is saved. The reason for this is because pickle does not save the model class itself. Rather, it saves a path to the file containing the class, which is used during load time. Because of this, your code can break in various ways when used in other projects or after refactors."

Comment: @DavidMiller actually I only need to save a `nn.Sequential model`. Do you know how to do that? I don't have a model class definition. For sequential I wrote this, hopefully a reputable answerer will confirm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923052/how-does-one-save-torch-nn-sequential-models-in-pytorch-properly

Comment: Then I use torch.save(model, file) it seems to drop batchnorm/dropout parameters because I never get same result then reload the model even if I make model.eval() pytorch 1.5 version. So you should use recommended way of saving just to avoid bugs I think

Answer (score 388, accepted):

Found [this page](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/761d6799beb3afa03657a71776412a2171ee7533/docs/source/notes/serialization.rst) on their github repo:

> ##### Recommended approach for saving a model
>
> There are two main approaches for serializing and restoring a model.
>
> The first (recommended) saves and loads only the model parameters:
>
> ```py
> torch.save(the_model.state_dict(), PATH)
> ```
>
> Then later:
>
> ```py
> the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
> the_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
> ```
>
> The second saves and loads the entire model:
>
> ```py
> torch.save(the_model, PATH)
> ```
>
> Then later:
>
> ```
> the_model = torch.load(PATH)
> ```
>
> However in this case, the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used, so it can break in various ways when used in other projects, or after some serious refactors.

---

See also: [Save and Load the Model](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html#save-and-load-the-model) section from the official PyTorch tutorials.

Comment: According to @smth https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/saving-and-loading-a-model-in-pytorch/2610/7 model reloads to train model by default. so need to manually call the_model.eval() after loading, if you are loading it for inference, not resuming training.

Comment: the second method gives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798009/pytorch-save-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied error on windows 10. wasn't able to solve it

Comment: Is there any option to save without a need for an access for model class?

Comment: With that approach how do you keep track of the *args and **kwargs you need to pass in for the load case?

Comment: actually I only need to save a `nn.Sequential` model. Do you know how to do that? I don't have a model class definition.

Comment: @CharlieParker sorry no idea, haven’t worked on pytorch for too long

Comment: @dontloo the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs). Running this command says NameError: name 'TheModelClass' is not defined.
How should I go about this

Comment: @NarenBabuR that was just a dummy name. You are to replace it with the actual model class you created or whichever predefined model you used from PyTorch. The args and kwargs are whatever you used for defining the model. You can save both the weights and biases as well as the extra parameters required to load the model in. See the second answer below.

Comment: I saved the rnn model using second method. After loading, i want to do predictions and calculate metrics such as F1. However, prediction doesn't work. I get this error `IndexError: index out of range in self` when running this: `predictions = model(batch.textt).squeeze(1)`

Comment: Hi guys, could anyone tell me what is the extension for model dict file(.pth?) and the extension for the entire model file(.pkl)??  Am I correct?

Comment: Note, that torch.save does NOT override an existing file and does so silently. Be aware when doing hyperparameter sweeps or such automated training runs ;)

Comment: In the linked page, I see that the loading terminates with model.eval(): does it mean we cannot restart training ?

Comment: What file extension should you use with `torch.save(model.state_dict(), filepath)`?

Comment: Does saving the model along with the model definition still work ?

Answer (score 260):

It depends on what you want to do.

**Case # 1: Save the model to use it yourself for inference**: You save the model, you restore it, and then you change the model to evaluation mode. This is done because you usually have `BatchNorm` and `Dropout` layers that by default are in train mode on construction:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), filepath)

#Later to restore:
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(filepath))
model.eval()
```

**Case # 2: Save model to resume training later**: If you need to keep training the model that you are about to save, you need to save more than just the model. You also need to save the state of the optimizer, epochs, score, etc. You would do it like this:

```
state = {
    'epoch': epoch,
    'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
    'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
    ...
}
torch.save(state, filepath)
```

To resume training you would do things like: `state = torch.load(filepath)`, and then, to restore the state of each individual object, something like this:

```
model.load_state_dict(state['state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(state['optimizer'])
```

Since you are resuming training, **DO NOT** call `model.eval()` once you restore the states when loading.

**Case # 3: Model to be used by someone else with no access to your code**:
In Tensorflow you can create a `.pb` file that defines both the architecture and the weights of the model. This is very handy, specially when using `Tensorflow serve`.  The equivalent way to do this in Pytorch would be:

```
torch.save(model, filepath)

# Then later:
model = torch.load(filepath)
```

This way is still not bullet proof and since pytorch is still undergoing a lot of changes, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Is there a recommended file ending for the 3 cases? Or is it always .pth?

Comment: In the Case #3 `torch.load` returns just an OrderedDict. How do you get the model in order to make predictions?

Comment: Hi, May I know how to do the mentioned "Case # 2: Save model to resume training later"? I managed to load the checkpoint to model, then I unable to run or resume to train model like "model.to(device)
model = train_model_epoch(model, criterion, optimizer, sched, epochs)"

Comment: Hi, for case one which is for inference, in the official pytorch doc say that must save optimizer state_dict for either inference or completing training. "When saving a general checkpoint, to be used for either inference or resuming training, you must save more than just the model’s state_dict. It is important to also save the optimizer’s state_dict, as this contains buffers and parameters that are updated as the model trains. "

Comment: In case #3, model class should be defined somewhere.

Comment: [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488795/unpickling-saved-pytorch-model-throws-attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-net) dives into some of the mess of Case #3.  I've written a similar model saver for Keras, and this process of saving the model source code is inherently messy.

Comment: For use case #3, you probably want a model exchange format like ONNX rather than pickling the whole model.

Comment: Same question here, what are the extensions for these 3 cases? I know there are .pth, .pkl, but could someone do the mapping between extension names and the cases??

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid yet it would be .pt file

Comment: In case #1, does it function by itself or do we need have certain files in the directory? I'm not fully understanding the difference between case #1 and #3

Answer (score 36):

The [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) Python library implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object.

When you `import torch` (or when you use PyTorch) it will `import pickle` for you and you don't need to call `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` directly, which are the methods to save and to load the object.

In fact, `torch.save()` and `torch.load()` will wrap `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` for you.

A `state_dict` the other answer mentioned deserves just a few more notes.

What `state_dict` do we have inside PyTorch?
There are actually two `state_dict`s.

The PyTorch model is `torch.nn.Module` which has `model.parameters()` call to get learnable parameters (w and b).
These learnable parameters, once randomly set, will update over time as we learn.
Learnable parameters are the first `state_dict`.

The second `state_dict` is the optimizer state dict. You recall that the optimizer is used to improve our learnable parameters. But the optimizer `state_dict` is fixed. Nothing to learn there.

Because `state_dict` objects are Python dictionaries, they can be easily saved, updated, altered, and restored, adding a great deal of modularity to PyTorch models and optimizers.

Let's create a super simple model to explain this:

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

model = torch.nn.Linear(5, 2)

# Initialize optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

print("Model's state_dict:")
for param_tensor in model.state_dict():
    print(param_tensor, "\t", model.state_dict()[param_tensor].size())

print("Model weight:")    
print(model.weight)

print("Model bias:")    
print(model.bias)

print("---")
print("Optimizer's state_dict:")
for var_name in optimizer.state_dict():
    print(var_name, "\t", optimizer.state_dict()[var_name])
```

This code will output the following:

```
Model's state_dict:
weight      torch.Size([2, 5])
bias      torch.Size([2])
Model weight:
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.1328,  0.1360,  0.1553, -0.1838, -0.0316],
        [ 0.0479,  0.1760,  0.1712,  0.2244,  0.1408]], requires_grad=True)
Model bias:
Parameter containing:
tensor([ 0.4112, -0.0733], requires_grad=True)
---
Optimizer's state_dict:
state      {}
param_groups      [{'lr': 0.001, 'momentum': 0.9, 'dampening': 0, 'weight_decay': 0, 'nesterov': False, 'params': [140695321443856, 140695321443928]}]
```

Note this is a minimal model. You may try to add stack of sequential

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
          torch.nn.Conv2d(A, B, C)
          torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
        )
```

Note that only layers with learnable parameters (convolutional layers, linear layers, etc.) and registered buffers (batchnorm layers) have entries in the model's `state_dict`.

Non-learnable things belong to the optimizer object `state_dict`, which contains information about the optimizer's state, as well as the hyperparameters used.

The rest of the story is the same; in the inference phase (this is a phase when we use the model after training) for predicting; we do predict based on the parameters we learned. So for the inference, we just need to save the parameters `model.state_dict()`.

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), filepath)
```

And to use later
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(filepath))
model.eval()

Note: Don't forget the last line `model.eval()` this is crucial after loading the model.

Also don't try to save `torch.save(model.parameters(), filepath)`. The `model.parameters()` is just the generator object.

On the other hand, `torch.save(model, filepath)` saves the model object itself, but keep in mind the model doesn't have the optimizer's `state_dict`. Check the other excellent answer by @Jadiel de Armas to save the optimizer's state dict.

Comment: Although it is not a straightforward solution, the essence of the problem is deeply analyzed! Upvote.

Comment: in `model.load_state_dict`, what is the `model`? If I'm exporting it to another environment, what would be the code sample to export and then import my model? I'm training a Bert. not sure what class to use to then load these parameters into

Answer (score 23):

**A common PyTorch convention is to save models using either a .pt or .pth file extension.**

Save/Load Entire Model

**Save:**

```
path = "username/directory/lstmmodelgpu.pth"
torch.save(trainer, path)
```

**Load:**

(Model class must be defined somewhere)

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

Comment: it raised: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'

Answer (score 17):

If you want to save the model and wants to resume the training later:

**Single GPU:**
Save:

```
state = {
        'epoch': epoch,
        'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
}
savepath='checkpoint.t7'
torch.save(state,savepath)
```

Load:

```
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint.t7')
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
```

**Multiple GPU:**
Save

```
state = {
        'epoch': epoch,
        'state_dict': model.module.state_dict(),
        'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
}
savepath='checkpoint.t7'
torch.save(state,savepath)
```

Load:

```
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint.t7')
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

#Don't call DataParallel before loading the model otherwise you will get an error

model = nn.DataParallel(model) #ignore the line if you want to load on Single GPU
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Saving locally](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)

How you save your model depends on how you want to access it in the future. If you can call a new instance of the `model` class, then all you need to do is save/load the weights of the model with `model.state_dict()`:

```py
# Save:
torch.save(old_model.state_dict(), PATH)

# Load:
new_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
new_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

If you cannot for whatever reason (or prefer the simpler syntax), then you can save the entire model (actually a reference to the file(s) defining the model, along with its state_dict) with `torch.save()`:

```
# Save:
torch.save(old_model, PATH)

# Load:
new_model = torch.load(PATH)
```

But since this is a reference to the location of the files defining the model class, this code is not portable unless those files are also ported in the same directory structure.

### Saving to cloud - [TorchHub](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html)

If you wish your model to be portable, you can easily allow it to be imported with `torch.hub`. If you add an appropriately defined `hubconf.py` file to a github repo, this can be easily called from within PyTorch to enable users to load your model with/without weights:

`hubconf.py` ([github.com/repo_owner/repo_name](https://github.com/repo_owner/repo_name))

```py
dependencies = ['torch']
from my_module import mymodel as _mymodel

def mymodel(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    return _mymodel(pretrained=pretrained, **kwargs)
```

Loading model:

```py
new_model = torch.hub.load('repo_owner/repo_name', 'mymodel')
new_model_pretrained = torch.hub.load('repo_owner/repo_name', 'mymodel', pretrained=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

pip install pytorch-lightning

make sure your parent model uses pl.LightningModule instead of nn.Module

[Saving and loading checkpoints using pytorch lightning](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/weights_loading.html)

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl

model = MyLightningModule(hparams)
trainer.fit(model)
trainer.save_checkpoint("example.ckpt")
new_model = MyModel.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_path="example.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach, hope it will be useful for you.

```
num_labels = len(test_label_cols)
robertaclassificationtrain = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/PM/TC/roberta_model'
robertaclassificationpath = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/PM/TC/ROBERTACLASSIFICATION"

model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(robertaclassificationpath, 
num_labels=num_labels)
model.cuda()

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(robertaclassificationtrain))
model.eval()
```

Where I save my train model already in 'roberta_model' path. Save a train model.

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/PM/TC/roberta_model')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Export/Load Model in TorchScript Format** is another way of saving model

Another common way to do inference with a trained model is to use TorchScript, an intermediate representation of a PyTorch model that can be run in Python as well as in C++.

**NOTE**: Using the TorchScript format, you will be able to load the exported model and run inference without defining the model class.

```
class TheModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Initialize model
model = TheModelClass()
```

Export:

```
model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model) # Export to TorchScript
model_scripted.save('model_scripted.pt') # Save
```

Load [ Works w/o defining model class ]:

```
model = torch.jit.load('model_scripted.pt')
model.eval()
```

[image]

```
       **Model arch in Netron looks like this**
```

Answer (score 0):

These days everything is written in the official tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

You have several options on how to save and what to save and all is explained in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

save:
`torch.save(model, file_path)`

load:
`model_save = torch.load(file_path)`

**Note**:

- *comment* **for**(training cycle) after train the dataset
- and keep the **model class** (like the RNN class)
- As long as you want to load the model without training, there will be no errors