# Load pytorch model from different working directory

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to load and access a pretrained model from the directory outside where all files are saved. Here is how directory structure is:

```
-MyProject
----Model_checkpoint_and_scripts
------access_model.py
--run_model.py
--other files
```

When run model calls access_model.py it looks for model.py in current working directory and does not find it. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch), I could use

```
the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
the_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

But in this case what is a good way to save all the arguments to initialize the model? I am thinking to pickle the command line args but there are some arguments like vocab size which are calculated.

Thanks

Comment: I am wondering whether your question is related to loading pre-trained models from a different working directory or you want to save arguments which initialized the model? To save arguments to initialize the model, you can simply put arguments in a dictionary and save it any file, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I want to save the arguments to initialize the model. Yes, I could put them in a dict and save, which I am able to do currently. I was looking for a better way.

Comment: better in what aspect? how are you thinking to improve?

Comment: If there is a way I could provide model class file location also... so that the_model = torch.load(PATH) works, which currently is not working because it looks explicitly for model.py in the current directory. It will be easy to distribute the trained model.

Comment: Essentially, now I will have to save 2 files. Which is not looking good(to me only maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to load it by adding the following lines:

```
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(here)
```