# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model file which looks like this

```
OrderedDict([('inp.conv1.conv.weight', 
          (0 ,0 ,0 ,.,.) = 
           -1.5073e-01  6.4760e-02  1.9156e-01
            1.2175e-01  3.5886e-02  1.3992e-01
           -1.5903e-01  8.2055e-02  1.7820e-01
          
          (0 ,0 ,1 ,.,.) = 
            1.0604e-01 -1.3653e-01  1.4803e-01
            6.0276e-02 -1.4674e-02  2.3059e-06
           -6.2192e-02 -5.1061e-03 -7.4145e-03
          
          (0 ,0 ,2 ,.,.) = 
           -5.5632e-02  3.5326e-02  6.5108e-02
            1.1411e-01 -4.4160e-02  8.2610e-02
            8.9979e-02 -3.5454e-02  4.2549e-02
          
          (1 ,0 ,0 ,.,.) = 
            4.8523e-02 -4.3961e-02  5.3614e-02
           -1.2644e-01  1.2777e-01  8.9547e-02
            3.8392e-02  2.7016e-02 -1.4552e-01
          
          (1 ,0 ,1 ,.,.) = 
            9.5537e-02  2.8748e-02  3.9772e-02
           -6.2410e-02  1.1264e-01  7.8663e-02
           -2.6374e-02  1.4401e-01 -1.7109e-01
          
          (1 ,0 ,2 ,.,.) = 
            5.1791e-02 -1.6388e-01 -1.7605e-01
            3.5028e-02  7.7164e-02 -1.4499e-01
           -2.9189e-02  2.7064e-03 -2.3228e-02
          
          (2 ,0 ,0 ,.,.) = 
           -7.4446e-03 -9.7202e-02 -1.4704e-01
           -1.0019e-02  8.1780e-02 -5.3530e-02
           -1.8412e-01  1.5988e-01 -1.3450e-01
          
          (2 ,0 ,1 ,.,.) = 
           -1.1075e-01 -5.2478e-02  6.0658e-02
            1.6739e-01 -2.9360e-02  1.2621e-01
            2.0686e-02  1.1468e-01  1.2282e-01
```

I want to do inference on this model, but when i do model.eval() i get,

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'eval
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is not a model file, instead, this is a state file. In a model file, the complete model is stored, whereas in a state file only the parameters are stored.
So, your `OrderedDict` are just values for your model. You will need to create the model and then need to load these values into your model. So, the process will be something in form of

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class TempModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 5, (3, 3))
    def forward(self, inp):
        return self.conv1(inp)

model = TempModel()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(file_path))
model.eval()
```

You'll need to define your model properly. The one given in the example above is just a dummy. If you construct your model yourself, you might need to update the keys of the saved dict file as mentioned [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-part-of-pre-trained-model/1113/2). The best course of action is to define your model in exactly the same way from when the `state_dict` was saved and then directly executing `model.load_state_dict` will work.

Comment: Is there a way to save the model so that it wont need redefinition when used?

Comment: You can take a look at this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch

Answer (score 4):

Simply use:

```
torch.save(model_conv,'cnn.pt')
the_model = torch.load('cnn.pt')
```

Comment: The author has got the OrderedDict structure. This approach is correct in case when one has the whole model stored, not the parameters only, and wants to load it.