# How does one save torch.nn.Sequential models in pytorch properly?

Tags: pytorch

I am very well aware of loading the dictionary and then having a instance of be loaded with the old dictionary of parameters (e.g. [this great question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch)). Unfortunately, when I have a `torch.nn.Sequential` I of course do not have a class definition for it.

So I wanted to double check, what is the proper way to do it. I believe `torch.save` is sufficient (so far my code has not collapsed), though these things can be more subtle than one might expect (e.g. I get a warning when I use pickle but `torch.save` uses it internally so it's confusing). Also, numpy has it's own save functions (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425878/1601580)) which tend to be more efficient, so there might be a subtle trade off I might be overlooking.

---

My test code:

```
# creating data and running through a nn and saving it

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from pathlib import Path
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np

import pickle

path = Path('~/data/tmp/').expanduser()
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

num_samples = 3
Din, Dout = 1, 1
lb, ub = -1, 1

x = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples, Din))

f = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('f1', nn.Linear(Din,Dout)),
    ('out', nn.SELU())
]))
y = f(x)

# save data torch to numpy
x_np, y_np = x.detach().cpu().numpy(), y.detach().cpu().numpy()
np.savez(path / 'db', x=x_np, y=y_np)

print(x_np)
# save model
with open('db_saving_seq', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump({'f': f}, file)

# load model
with open('db_saving_seq', 'rb') as file:
    db = pickle.load(file)
    f2 = db['f']

# test that it outputs the right thing
y2 = f2(x)

y_eq_y2 = y == y2
print(y_eq_y2)

db2 = {'f': f, 'x': x, 'y': y}
torch.save(db2, path / 'db_f_x_y')

print('Done')

db3 = torch.load(path / 'db_f_x_y')
f3 = db3['f']
x3 = db3['x']
y3 = db3['y']
yy3 = f3(x3)

y_eq_y3 = y == y3
print(y_eq_y3)

y_eq_yy3 = y == yy3
print(y_eq_yy3)
```

---

Related:

- related question from forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-save-nn-sequential-as-a-model/89117/14

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the code `torch.nn.Sequential` is based on `torch.nn.Module`:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/container.html#Sequential

So you can use

```
f = torch.nn.Sequential(...)
torch.save(f.state_dict(), path)
```

just like with any other `torch.nn.Module`.