# How to detect the given model is a keras or scikit model using python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

If I want to determine the type of model i.e. from which framework was it made programmatically, is there a way to do that?
I have a model in some serialized manner(Eg. a .h5 file). For simplicity purposes, assume that my model can be either tensorflow's or scikit learn's. How can I determine programmatically which one of these 2 is the one?

Comment: Partial answer: [Determine whether a model is pytorch model or a tensorflow model or scikit model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849520/determine-whether-a-model-is-pytorch-model-or-a-tensorflow-model-or-scikit-model/64850684#64850684)

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `type(model)` to see its type

you can also use `help(model)` to get the doc string from model.

you can also use `dir(model)` to see its member function or parameters.

you can also use `import inspect` `inspect.getsource(model)` to get source code of a object.