# how to save a Pytorch model?

Tags: pytorch

I am new to Deep learning and I want to know, how can I save the final model in Pytorch? I tried some things that were mentioned but I got confused with, how to save the model and how to load it back?

Comment: Please notice that Pytorch questions are expected to be tagged as such (edited).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to save a trained model in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2):

to save:

```py
# save the weights of the model to a .pt file
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "your_model_path.pt")
```

to load:

```py
# load your model architecture/module
model = YourModel()
# fill your architecture with the trained weights
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("your_model_path.pt"))
```

Comment: I save the model using a torch.save() method, but I have a problem now understanding how I will load it. Do I have to create a different program for that and if yes, which parameters I have to pass. how many things will the load function take from the saved model.?

Comment: what do you mean by "different program"? You can load the .pt file from any script you want. I normally have two functions, train() and test(). In train() I train the model and in every epoch I save it. In test() I just load the model..

Comment: can we put the save function and the load function in the same program, when we have to run it later?