# Is there a way to load torchvision model by string?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

Currently, I load pretrained torchvision model using following code:

```
import torchvision
torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=True)
```

However, I'd love to have model name as string parameter and then load the pretrained model using that string. A pseudo-code that would do so would be something like:

```
model_name = 'resnet101'
torchvision.models.get(model_name)(pretrained=True)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a rather simple manner?

Comment: Related (loading via string from torch.hub): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

`getattr(torchvision.models, 'resnet101')(pretrained=True)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [torch.hub](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html):

```
model_str = 'resnet50'
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision', model_str, pretrained=True)
```

---

All the available models by strings can be found via:

```
torch.hub.list('pytorch/vision', force_reload=True)
```

output:

```
['alexnet',
 'deeplabv3_mobilenet_v3_large',
 'deeplabv3_resnet101',
 'deeplabv3_resnet50',
 'densenet121',
 'densenet161',
 'densenet169',
 'densenet201',
 'fcn_resnet101',
 'fcn_resnet50',
 'googlenet',
 'inception_v3',
 'lraspp_mobilenet_v3_large',
 'mnasnet0_5',
 'mnasnet0_75',
 'mnasnet1_0',
 'mnasnet1_3',
 'mobilenet_v2',
 'mobilenet_v3_large',
 'mobilenet_v3_small',
 'resnet101',
 'resnet152',
 'resnet18',
 'resnet34',
 'resnet50',
 'resnext101_32x8d',
 'resnext50_32x4d',
 'shufflenet_v2_x0_5',
 'shufflenet_v2_x1_0',
 'squeezenet1_0',
 'squeezenet1_1',
 'vgg11',
 'vgg11_bn',
 'vgg13',
 'vgg13_bn',
 'vgg16',
 'vgg16_bn',
 'vgg19',
 'vgg19_bn',
 'wide_resnet101_2',
 'wide_resnet50_2']
```