# How to use a PyTorch model trained in python in OCaml?

Tags: python, pytorch, ocaml

I am trying to use a model which is already trained (I have stored the state_dict in a .pth file) in OCaml. I have been attempting to install [OCaml-torch](https://github.com/LaurentMazare/ocaml-torch). However, I faced some issues installing and using the library.

While following the installation instructions [Downloaded and unzipped Libtorch] -

```
export LIBTORCH=./libtorch
git clone https://github.com/LaurentMazare/ocaml-torch.git
cd ocaml-torch
make clean
make all
```

I get the following error -

```
File "src/stubs/torch_bindings_generated.ml", line 8309, characters 2-16:
Error: Multiple definition of the type name t.
       Names must be unique in a given structure or signature.
File "src/wrapper/torch_bindings_generated.ml", line 8309, characters 2-16:
Error: Multiple definition of the type name t.
       Names must be unique in a given structure or signature.
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Let me know a way to overcome the above error. Thanks!

PS: Is there any other way to use a model in OCaml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytorch load model without torchvision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813681/pytorch-load-model-without-torchvision)

Comment: Not really there are no inherent library bindings for loading pytorch functions in OCaml. I have to do a forward pass for samples in OCaml which won't be possible. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify on the issues you faced installing the library? Someone here may be able to assist. Otherwise requests for software or libraries are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris I have updated the question! Sorry for providing an unclear question earlier.

Comment: From the error message I can tell that you're building the bindings using a too old version of OCaml. Use `opam` to install a more modern version and try again.

Comment: If you have opam installed, you might as well use it to install ocaml-torch.

Comment: @Chris opam install torch only installs the CPU version of ocaml-torch. I would like to have a GPU accelerated version.

Comment: @ivg I can't really update the ocaml version. It is a dependency for the rest of the project and I couldn't find a way to install an older version of ocaml-torch with GPU compatibility. Thanks!

Comment: Then you're in trouble. You can try to modify the bindings but I would suggest persuading your team to upgrade the OCaml version, at least to 4.09.

Comment: You can also ask the ocaml-torch maintainers to make the bindings more portable. It is a bit of work but is doable.