# How can I load a model in pytorch without having to remember the parameters used?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training a model in pytorch for which I have made a class like so:

```
from torch import nn

class myNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dense1=128, dense2=64, dense3=32, ...):
         self.MLP = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dense1, dense2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(dense2, dense3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(dense3, 1)
         )
         ...
```

In order to save it I am using:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_model_path)
```

and to load it I am using:

```
model = myNN()   # or with specified parameters
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_file))
```

However, in order for this method to work I have to use the right values in myNN()'s constructor. That means that I would need to somehow remember or store which parameters (layer sizes) I have used in each case in order to properly load different models.

Is there a flexible way to save/load models in pytorch where I would also read the size of the layers?

E.g. by loading a myNN() object directly or somehow reading the layer sizes from the saved pickle file?

I am hesitant to try the second method in [Best way to save a trained model in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch) due to the warnings mentioned there. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed serializing the whole Python is quite a drastic move. Instead, you can always add user-defined items in the saved file: you can save the model's state along with its class parameters. Something like this would work:

1. First save your arguments in the instance such that we can serialize them when saving the model:

   ```
   class myNN(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, dense1=128, dense2=64, dense3=32):
           super().__init__()
           self.kwargs = {'dense1': dense1, 'dense2': dense2, 'dense3': dense3}
           self.MLP = nn.Sequential(
               nn.Linear(dense1, dense2),
               nn.ReLU(),
               nn.Linear(dense2, dense3),
               nn.ReLU(),
               nn.Linear(dense3, 1))
   ```
2. We can save the parameters of the model along with its initializer arguments:

   ```
   >>> torch.save([model.kwargs, model.state_dict()], path)
   ```
3. Then load it:

   ```
   >>> kwargs, state = torch.load(path)
   >>> model = myNN(**kwargs)
   >>> model.load_state_dict(state)
   <All keys matched successfully>
   ```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, now I don't have to remember what I used for each saved model!