# How can i save model while training in torch

Tags: python, deep-learning, torch, huggingface-transformers, roberta

I am training RoBERTa model for a new language, and it takes some hours to train the data. So I think it is a good idea to save the model while training so that I can continue training the model from where it stops next time.

I am using torch library and google Colab GPU to train the model.

Here is my colab file.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jOYCaLdxYRwGMqMciG6c3yPYZAsZRySZ?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to save a trained model in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch)

Comment: I do not want to save a trained model. I want to save it while training, so if it stops training for some reason I can re-run it and it can continue training from where it stops.

Comment: A "trained model" doesn't mean a model that has finished its training step. It simply mean a model that was trained. A model that trained an epoch out of a 100 epochs is indeed a "trained model". Have you looked at the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Trainer`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer) from transformers to train the model. This trainer will also need you to specify the [`TrainingArguments`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments), which will allow you to save checkpoints of the model while training.

Some of the parameters you set when creating `TrainingArguments` are:

- `save_strategy`: The checkpoint save strategy to adopt during training. Possible values are:

  - "no": No save is done during training.
  - "epoch": Save is done at the end of each epoch.
  - "steps": Save is done every save_steps.
- `save_steps`: Number of updates steps before two checkpoint saves if save_strategy="steps".
- `save_total_limit`: If a value is passed, will limit the total amount of checkpoints. Deletes the older checkpoints in output_dir.
- `load_best_model_at_end`: Whether or not to load the best model found during training at the end of training.

One important thing about `load_best_model_at_end` is that when set to True, the parameter `save_strategy` needs to be the same as `eval_strategy`, and in the case it is “steps”, `save_steps` must be a round multiple of eval_steps.