# Saving a torch model in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using the azure ml documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-bring-data to train a deep learning model. I want to save the model in the specified path. This is my original script [run-pytorch-data.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmSfk.png)

the train.py script is as follows :
[train.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNSKi.png)

the model is not getting saved in the specified location when I printed the current working directory it gives:

```
  print (os.getcwd())
   /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/workspacecvazue/azureml/day1-experiment-data_1646679122_86b0ac64/wd/azureml/day1-experiment-data_1646679122_86b0ac64
```

how can I save the model in the desired location?

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the following ways to save the torch model in Azure ML:

As suggested by [User Jadiel de Armas - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2701950/jadiel-de-armas):

**1. Save the model to use it yourself for inference:**

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), filepath)   
#Later to restore:  
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(filepath))
model.eval()
```

**2. Save model to resume training later:**

```
state = {
    'epoch': epoch,
    'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
    'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
    ...
}
torch.save(state, filepath)
```

**3. **Model to be used by someone else with no access to your code****:

```
torch.save(model, filepath)
#Then later:
model = torch.load(filepath)
```

**References: [python - Best way to save a trained model in PyTorch? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch), [Saving and Loading Models — PyTorch Tutorials 1.10.1+cu102 documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) and [Save and Load the Model — PyTorch Tutorials 1.10.1+cu102 documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html#save-and-load-the-model)

Answer (score 0):

when you train a model in azure ML it's trained in a distant compute once the training is complete and the model saved, you must upload the model in your environement so

**first step** : save the model in the compute

```
torch.save(state, path_save + '/model.hdf5')
#Then later:
```

**second step** : upload the model in your account/blob storage

```
datastore.upload(src_dir=path_save,
                 target_path=desired_path, overwrite=True)
```