# Can I train my pretrained model with a totally different architecture?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, transfer-learning, resnet

I have trained a pretrained **ResNet18** model with my custom dataset on **Pytorch** and wondered whether I could transfer my model file to train another one with a different architecture, e.g. **ResNet50**. I know I have to save my model accordingly *(explained well on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49078976/12965067) here)* but this was a question that I have never thought before. 
I was planning to use more advanced models like **VisionTransformers** (*ViT*) but I couldn't figure out whether I had to start with a pretrained ViT already or I could just take my previous model file and use it as the pretrained model to train a ViT.

Example Scenario: `ResNet18 --> ResNet50 --> Inception v3 --> ViT`

My best guess it that it's not possible due to number of weights, neurons and layer structures but I would love to hear that if I miss a crucial point here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between models that only differ in number of layers (Resnet-18 and Resnet-50), it has been done to initialize some layers of the larger model from the weights of the smaller model's layers. Inversely, you can truncate a larger model by taking a subset of regularly spaced layers and initialize a smaller model. In both cases, you need to retrain everything at the end if you hope to achieve semi-decent performances.

The whole point of using architectures that vastly differ (vision transformers vs CNNs) is to learn different features from the inputs and unlock new levels of semantic understanding. Recent models like BeiT also use new self-supervised training schemes that have nothing to do with the classic ImageNet pretraining. Using trained weights from another model would go against the point.

Having said that,if you want to use a ViT, why not start from the available pretrained weights on [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=image-classification&sort=downloads&search=vit) and fine-tune it on the data you used to train your ResNet50 ?

Comment: As you wrote, I will most likely go for a pretrained state-of-art model with my data. Thanks for the answer. It shed a perfect light on the foggy grounds of my DL side of my brain :D

Comment: the resnet50 and resnet101 share  the same layers structure for the n base layers ( not sure about n)
since  resnets are made of layers equivalent to y=x + F(x), you can just try to set F to the null fonction for the top layers and initiliaze the first ones with those of resnet50