# saving training models in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I save models after each epoch so that I can pick the best model with lowest loss for testing? This is my training loop:

```
  # get the model using our helper function
    model = get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes)

  # move model to the right device
    model.to(device)

    PATH = 'home/Train/ArT_dataset/models/'
    ml =[] 
    vl = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        loss_value = train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        ml.append(loss_value)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        #evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
        #val_loss = eval_forward(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
        val_loss  = evaluate_loss(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
        #print(val_loss)
        # val_loss = evaluate_loss(model,data_loader_val, device)
        vl.append(val_loss)
        torch.save(model, PATH)
    print(ml,vl)
    draw_loss(ml,vl)
```

error says me:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/Train/ArT_dataset/models/'
```

I followed this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119670/15147370 but nothing. +

And tried with this:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(PATH, 'epoch-{}.pt'.format(epoch)))
```

and the same error I got:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/Train/ArT_dataset/models/epoch-0.pt'
```

Please can somebody help

Comment: your path should be probably `PATH = '/home/Train/ArT_dataset/models/'`. It starts with `/`

Comment: Wow, yeah that's it, it works. Sry I'm stupid because I didn't see that. Thanks :)