# Saving and Loading PyTorch Models for Inference without Model Definition

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working on a PyTorch project where I need to save and then later load a model for inference in an environment where the model definition is not available. Essentially, I want to load the model (including its architecture, weights, and biases) directly from the saved file and perform predictions without explicitly defining the model class in the new environment.

So far, I've tried the conventional method of saving and loading the state dictionary as suggested in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/how-do-i-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch):

```
the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
the_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

However, this approach didnt work for me, it failed to export the model definition from the .pt file in the different python file.

I've also explored using TorchScript with torch.jit and torch.save to create a RecursiveScriptModule. While this seems to be a solution, my existing pipeline is quite complex, and I'm concerned about compatibility issues. Specifically, my question is: If I successfully convert my model to a RecursiveScriptModule, will it seamlessly replace the typical .pt file loaded using torch.load in my existing workflow?

Additionally, I'm considering ONNX as an alternative, but I'm unsure how to integrate it into my current workflow. Can ONNX be a viable solution for this scenario, and if so, how can I transition to using it without major disruptions?