# PyTorch and Pickle Error: AttributeError: Can't get attribute "Class_name" on <module '__main__' from '/load_model.py'>

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pickle

I have created a neural network model using PyTorch for a time-series forecasting problem. I have saved the model using Pickle.
When loading the model to check on test data, it is throwing an attribute error.
Below, I'm providing the relevant parts of my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class twoD_predict(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()

  def forward(self,x):
  ...

  def train(self,
        epochs = 100):
  ...

obj1 = twoD_predict()

obj1.train()
```

I saved the model using Pickle as follows:

```
import pickle
filename = (f"{column_names[0]}.sav")
pickle.dump(obj1, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

However, when I try to load the model with the following code:

```
import pickle
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("model.sav", 'rb') as file:
        model = pickle.load(file)
```

I encounter the error: `"AttributeError: Can't get attribute "twoD_predict" on <module '__main__' from '/load_model.py'>"`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Not sure this is the best way of saving the model. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/how-do-i-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ForceBru, Is there a way to convert a model saved using pickle to torch's format? The problem is I have saved 20 models this way, and each takes considerable time to train. If there's a way to convert it, it would be helpful.

Comment: As the other answer says, you could try importing `twoD_predict` into `load_model.py` before calling `pickle.load`

Answer (score 0):

Have you try import `twoD_predict` to the file you want to load the model? The pickled version still requires things to replicate on how to recreate the structure of your model (e.g. you have to load the definition of the model to your current file). If you don't want to do that, considering export your model in TorchScript format.